# can't commit network settings via command line

Tags: terminal, network, wifi, python

I'm writing a Python script that changes network settings with commands like `networksetup -setv4off 'PANTECH UML295'` and `networksetup -setdhcp 'PANTECH UML295'`. When I enter these in Terminal, I enter my root password, and then nothing changes in Network settings. Enabling/disabling WiFi using `networksetup setairportpower en1 off` seems to work fine, however. Any idea on what might be the problem? Can't seem to find anything through search. Thanks.

Comment: You won't see anything change in the network settings, you have go to the advanced setting, to see those. Also I assume you skipped clientid argument in the `-setdhcp` here. Do `networksetup -getinfo PANTECH\ UML295` to see the changes.

Comment: @user14492 All I want to do is change the `Configure IPv4` under Network settings between `Using DHCP` and `Off`, which I had been able to do before. I'm on a fresh install of OS X so I don't know what could be the problem.

Comment: It seems to work for me, to set it to off I just did `networksetup -setv4off Thunderbolt\ Ethernet` and to set it back to Using DHCP, `networksetup -setdhcp Thunderbolt\ Ethernet`. Make sure you're writing the name correctly, and for both the commands it needs the network service name. Which you can get by `networksetup -listallnetworkservices`. Try those commands in the Terminal and see if they produce any errors.

Comment: @user14492 That is strange. That is exactly what I've been doing and still nothing changes after entering root password.